# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    for ( var i = 0; i < members.length; i++ ) {

        var value = value[i];
        console.log(value);

    }
```

Really confused how this could possibly be wrong...

'i' is defined at zero so not sure how it could not find the value.

Below is the whole of my controller code.

```
 angular.module(module.name).controller(module.name + '.c.' + current.name, [
        '$scope',
        '$stateParams',
        'members',
        'assessment', 
        '$localStorage',  

    function (scope, stateParams, members, assessment, $localStorage) {
        scope.members = members;        
        // Asessment and item scope variables
        scope.assessment = assessment;             

        scope.active = $localStorage.$default({
            value : false
        });  

        console.log(members.length);      

        // This isn't doing anything much atm apart from firing the 
        // console logs
        scope.change = function (active) {

            if (active) {
                scope.active = $localStorage.$default({
                    value : true
                });
                console.log('hi 1');
            } else {
                scope.active = $localStorage.$default({
                    value : false
                });
                console.log('hi 2');
            }
        };   

        for ( var i = 0; i < members.length; i++ ) {

            var value = value[i];
            console.log(value);
        }
    }
]);
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I was after:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < members.length; i++ ) {

        value = "value" + i;

        console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Obviously `value` is undefined when accessed first time

Comment: shouldnt `var value = value[i];` be `var value = members[i];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment on previous answer you may want like this

```
for ( var i = 0; i < members.length; i++ ) {
        console.log('value' + i);
}
```

so output will be:

value0

value1

value2

.....

and if you want to show member values

```
for ( var i = 0; i < members.length; i++ ) {
     console.log(members[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was after:         for ( var i = 0; i < members.length; i++ ) {

            value = "value" + i;

            console.log(value);

        }

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the `value` has either `true` or `false`. So you need to remove the line:

```
value = value[i];
```

I guess you are trying to do, as the `members` is the one that has an array of values. Please change your code to:

```
value = members[i];
```

Comment: I need the value to allow the console.log to work. I'm basically trying to make a value that outputs value1, value2, value3 etc. any ideas what I need to do..

Comment: Just give `console.log("Value: " + i)`. That will do.